# Building an embedded framework for WatchOS and iOS in Xcode 8 with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit

I am in the process of porting an all iOS + WatchOS 1 app written originally in Swift 1, to the latest Xcode 8, WatchOS 3, Swift 3.

My app has an embedded framework with some common functionality that used to compile and run file for both the watchkit extension target and the ios app target.

With Xcode 8 I can no longer seem to get this to work.  When I try to `import` the framework in the watchkit extension code, I get the `module not found` error.

Is it still possible to compile and use one single embedded framework package on both the target iOS and WatchKit extension targets?  In my framework I have the target platforms set to `watchos, watchsimulator, iphoneos, iphonesimulator`.

My gut says it's not possible anymore.  Where originally all the code really ran on the phone itself, not that codes runs on the actual watch and the phone, you'd need to compile an embedded framework specifically for each.

Comment: I need to create new project which should use swift framework shared between iOS and WatchOS. Did you find any solution or hint, references for this?

Answer (score 6):

Short version: You can't. Create a duplicate target and set it to use the watch SDK.

Longer version from Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH21-SW1

including:

> NOTE
>
> After you create a separate framework target for your WatchKit
>   extension, you must manage the contents of that framework separately
>   for both iOS and watchOS. If you add files to the iOS version of the
>   framework, remember to add them to the watchOS version.

Answer (score 2):

Since Xcode 11 you can use Swift Package Manager to do this without duplicate targets. Have tested in Xcode 12 beta6 at least and it is another option to look at that didn't exist when the question was asked or I initially answered (and it doesn't meet the detailed requirements of the question as it needs newer Xcode).

Comment: Yes but the other is still the strictly true answer to the question (which specifies Xcode 8). I felt this is an entirely separate approach that is may be useful for some people and worth mentioning. By doing separately people can separately rate the answers to guide people in the best way and keeps comments to a sepecific answer.

Comment: I have tried this and have failed miserably. The problem is, that the link type checker in Xcode 12b5 fails before building. Even when you add iPhone and WatchOS as TargetBuildType.

Comment: I've just tried (Xcode 12beta6) and it all seemed to work. I created an iOS app project, created a swift package and added to the project then added a watch app target. Then I added the package to both the watch extension and the iOS App, added a public constant to the package to test with and then imported the package into a file in watch extension and iOS App then accessed the public constant. No changes to Package file made from the template. @Augunrik

Comment: Demoed here: https://github.com/josephlord/WatchiOSSPMDemo Not sure why you had issues.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I don't know what I did wrong. I'll check out your example to learn!