# Building a exsist framework for watchOS Simulator not working

Tags: ios, xcode, watch, xcode11.4

I am creating an apple watch app for my ios app and I want to use my core framework in the watch extension.

I did change the build setting for the core framework to build for the watch too, like this 
[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wa9v.png)

then linked my watch to the framework but I still get the Error.

"Building for watchOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'framework name' is building for iOS Simulator. You may need to configure 'framework name' to build for watchOS Simulator."

I did clean and rebuild the project but still getting the Error

xcode: 11.4.1

Comment: This may be answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397986/1254211